# Geometric median

Tags: python, python-3.x, computational-geometry

I have written some code to find the

> **[Geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median)** for a set of ***weighted points***

it is based on this [Google-kickstart](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/11304486/dashboard#s=p1) challenge . ***I don't want a better solution but want to know what is wrong in my code***

. The code iterates against given ***precision value of 10^-6*** to arrive to a value close to the geometric median  . the problem I face is it returns correct value for digits until 10^-3 and after that it goes wrong . I cannot figure out what is going wrong . *I also noted changing the initializing value alters the result* but don't know why.***The code also holds good if weight of points is not considered*** 
here is formula i use to find distance to each point: ***max(abs(i.x-k.x), abs(i.y-k.y))x(weight_of_i)***   (its is ***Chebyshev distance***)

here is the iteration function i used :

```
#c = previous centre , stp =previous step ,listy_r = list of points(x,y,wt) ,k = previous sum of distances
def move_ct( c,stp,listy_r,k):  #calculates the minimum centre itrateviely , returns c--> center,stp-->step,k-->sum of distances
while True:
    tmp=list()
    moves = [(c[0], c[1]+stp), (c[0], c[1]-stp),
            (c[0]+stp, c[1]), (c[0]-stp, c[1])]
    for each in moves:tmp.append(sdist(listy_r, each))
    tmp_min = min(tmp)
    if tmp_min < k:
        k = tmp_min
        index = tmp.index(tmp_min)
        c = moves[index]
        break
    else:
        stp *= 0.5   
return (c,stp,k)
```

here are the values i initialized:

1. initial geometric centre  = centroid of the weighted points
2. precision = 10**-6
3. step = half of distance between highest and lowest coordinates on x,y

I have attached an input text  file [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gZIRMmdDbnEjX3ZqxVjX1cVeKZfDkd3t/view?usp=sharing) that contains 10000 points(*it is test case 1 for large input for the challenge*) in the format
one point for each line and each point has 3 parameters (x,y,weight)
eg: 980.69 595.86 619.03    where

- 980.69 = x coordinate
- 595.86 = y coordinate
- 619.03 = weight

the result of the 10000 points should give :**3288079343.471880**  but it gives 
**3288079343.4719906** as result . **Notice it is off only after 10^-3 .**

Comment: You requirement exceeds the precision limit of `double` (~14 s.f.; Python uses these internally for floats), so the current result is as good as it can get.

Comment: what can i do to get the correct answer. I knew it was some thing wrong with python but was not sure

Comment: Post the whole code separately as a link (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and in particular 1) the definition of `sdist`, 2) how `move_ct` is being called, and 3) the types of `c` and `listy_r`.

Comment: I posted like that before and got -4 on my post and was suggested to cut-short and post only snippet anyways I will post link to full code here in next comment

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/178L4Egs1Xr1s06xSO5ISKsSL8U7tJgbT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the large input file can be found on google kickstart link I have posted

Comment: The problem lies not with your code but your interpretation of the pass condition: `y will be considered correct if it is within an absolute or relative error of 10^-6 of the correct answer`. The **relative** error is the *ratio* of the absolute error to the correct answer, and in this case its value is `3288079343.471880 * 10^-6 = 3288.07...` which is *much* greater than `10^-6` itself - so your code should pass with flying colours. Google's own result was probably computed with arbitrary / higher precision numerical types.

Comment: Is there any way I can mimic the result tweaking my code

Comment: As I said you could use a higher / arbitrary precision module such as [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) or [`PyGMP`](https://libraries.io/pypi/PyGMP).

Comment: Thanks I will try that and post results